# how to set @ControllerAdvice or @ExceptionHandler encoding to UTF-8?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat, controller, exceptionhandler

I use `Spring MVC`, `Tomcat 8.5.81` and `java-configured context`. Here is the controller class. If I send **ResponseEntity<?> with Cyrillic from here**, everything is represented on the client correctly.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/rooms", produces = {"application/json; charset=UTF-8"})
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class RoomController {
```

However, if I use my `@ControllerAdvice` to send custom exception with **Cyrillic description** on the client I got `??????` symbols.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    @ExceptionHandler(value = {
        NoSuchElementException.class,
        IllegalArgumentException.class,
        ServiceUnavailableException.class})
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleConflict(RuntimeException ex, WebRequest req) {
    String responseBody = ex.getMessage();
    return handleExceptionInternal(ex, responseBody, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, req);
    }
}
```

This is a part of my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<packaging>war</packaging>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    <hibernate.version>5.6.8.Final</hibernate.version>
</properties>
```

How to set encoding UTF-8 to @ControllerAdvice/@ExceptionHandler?

Comment: Can you share snippets of how you've set up the character encoding for your project? (your pom.xml, build.gradle etc. )

Comment: @IgorFlakiewicz has provided

Comment: I think it's because you add `new HttpHeaders()` in your exception handler, add a `"content-type"` header to it with the value `"application/json; charset=UTF-8"`.